# Calculate number of fields that are of type "None" in a struct Rust

Tags: rust, macros

I am working on a macro that computes the number of fields on a struct which are of type  None at runtime. I have an implementation that computes the number of fields for a struct. The source code is given below.

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::Cell;

macro_rules! generate {
    ($name:ident {$($field:ident : $t:ty),+}) => {
        struct $name { $($field: $t),+ }
        impl $name {
            fn field_count(&self) -> usize {
                generate!(@count $($field),+)
            }
        }
    };
    (@count $t1:tt, $($t:tt),+) => { 1 + generate!(@count $($t),+) };
    (@count $t:tt) => { 1 };
}

generate! { test1 { num: i32, s: Option<String> }}
generate! { test2 { num: i32, s: String }}

fn main() {
    let s = test1 { num: 0, s: None };
    println!("{}", s.field_count());
    let s = test2 { num: 0, s: String::new() };
    println!("{}", s.field_count());
}
```

The problem with this implementation is this returns the total number of fields in the
struct at compile time so for test1 and test1 the answer is always 2. I am looking for a way to modify the macro to compute fields that are of type "None" in the struct.

Comment: While you could use `TypeId` to check if two types are equivalent, `None` is not a type. `None` is a variant of the enum `Option<T>`. What are you trying to use this for? This sounds like the [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/). Rust types must be known at compile time and are not designed for this sort of dynamic programming. Perhaps a  data structure should be used instead?

Comment: Nitpick: your macro doesn't work with attributes and generics (not sure whether it needs to).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To distinguish `None`s, we first need to distinguish `Option`s. And this is little hard.

There are two ways to do that: syntactically or via the type system. Syntactically means that the macro will identify fields that have the type `Option<T>` (i.e. `Option` `<` type `>`). However, this requires a TT munching, will force you to parse the `ty` fragment type yourself (you cannot rely on it because you'll not be able to inspect into its composed tokens later), and as a bonus won't work if users will type-alias `Option`.

The type system approach is more robust. The idea is to create some trait, implemented for any type, with a method that for `Option<T>` will return `1` iff it is `Some` and for other types will always return `1`. This sounds like a perfect use case for [specialization](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/1210-impl-specialization.html) ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=567c41b435e36c6f5b836ead82fbbaeb)):

```rust
#![feature(min_specialization)]

pub trait OneIfSome {
    fn one_if_some(&self) -> usize;
}

impl<T> OneIfSome for T {
    default fn one_if_some(&self) -> usize { 1 }
}

impl<T> OneIfSome for Option<T> {
    fn one_if_some(&self) -> usize { self.is_some() as usize }
}

macro_rules! generate {
    ($name:ident {$($field:ident : $t:ty),+}) => {
        struct $name { $($field: $t),+ }
        
        impl $name {
            fn field_count(&self) -> usize {
                generate!(@count self $($field,)*)
            }
        }
    };
    (@count $self:ident $first_field:ident, $($rest:ident,)*) => {
        $crate::OneIfSome::one_if_some(&$self.$first_field)
            + generate!(@count $self $($rest,)*)
    };
    (@count $self:ident) => { 0 };
}
```

Unfortunately, specialization is unstable, and doesn't even have a clear path towards stabilization. Can we replace it with something stable?

And it turns out, yes! [@dtolnay invented a technique called "autoref specialization"](https://github.com/dtolnay/case-studies/blob/master/autoref-specialization/README.md) that is intended exactly for cases like that (specialization inside a macro). I won't explain how it works here (the linked article is a great read), but here is how you can apply it to your case ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f8c9b5c669e0bdb24488401d8fdf993c)):

```rust
pub trait OneIfSomeGeneral {
    fn one_if_some(&self) -> usize;
}
impl<T> OneIfSomeGeneral for &'_ T {
    fn one_if_some(&self) -> usize { 1 }
}

pub trait OneIfSomeOption {
    fn one_if_some(&self) -> usize;
}
impl<T> OneIfSomeOption for Option<T> {
    fn one_if_some(&self) -> usize { self.is_some() as usize }
}

macro_rules! generate {
    ($name:ident {$($field:ident : $t:ty),+}) => {
        struct $name { $($field: $t),+ }
        
        impl $name {
            fn field_count(&self) -> usize {
                #[allow(unused_imports)]
                use $crate::{OneIfSomeGeneral, OneIfSomeOption};
                
                generate!(@count self $($field,)*)
            }
        }
    };
    (@count $self:ident $first_field:ident, $($rest:ident,)*) => {
        (&$self.$first_field).one_if_some()
            + generate!(@count $self $($rest,)*)
    };
    (@count $self:ident) => { 0 };
}
```

(Note: There is a problem with the above code: if the field type has a method named `one_if_some()`, it will take priority. So choose an unambiguous name (`__my_generate_macro__one_if_some()`, perhaps?)).

Comment: I have another question posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73399496/get-name-of-fields-of-type-none-in-rust, where I would like to compute the names of the fields of type None.