# Get name of fields of type None in Rust

Tags: rust, macros

I am working on a macro that computes the number of fields on a struct which are of type None at runtime. I have an implementation that computes the number of fields for a struct. The source code is given below.

```
pub trait OneIfSomeGeneral {
    fn one_if_some(&self) -> usize;
}

impl<T> OneIfSomeGeneral for &'_ T {
    fn one_if_some(&self) -> usize { 1 }
}

pub trait OneIfSomeOption {
    fn one_if_some(&self) -> usize;
}

impl<T> OneIfSomeOption for Option<T> {
    fn one_if_some(&self) -> usize { self.is_some() as usize }
}

macro_rules! generate {
    ($name:ident {$($field:ident : $t:ty),+}) => {
        struct $name { $($field: $t),+ }
        
        impl $name {
            fn field_count(&self) -> usize {
                #[allow(unused_imports)]
                use $crate::{OneIfSomeGeneral, OneIfSomeOption};
                
                generate!(@count self $($field,)*)
            }
        }
    };
    (@count $self:ident $first_field:ident, $($rest:ident,)*) => {
        (&$self.$first_field).one_if_some()
            + generate!(@count $self $($rest,)*)
    };
    (@count $self:ident) => { 0 };
}

generate! { Test1 { num: i32, s: Option<String> }}
generate! { Test2 { num: i32, s: String }}

fn main() {
    let s = Test1 { num: 0, s: None };
    println!("{}", s.field_count());
    let s = Test2 { num: 0, s: String::new() };
    println!("{}", s.field_count());
}
```

The source code works fine except for the case when I want to know the name of the fields that are of type None.I am looking for a way to modify the macro to compute names of fields that are of type "None" in the struct.

Comment: And output them as?

Comment: `None` is not a type. It's a value of type `Option<T>`.

Comment: This question needs a few clarifications.  The first part of your question states you are looking for the _count_ of fields. The second part of the question states you are looking for their _names_. It would also be helpful if you could explain what your actual goal with this macro is – chances are there are better solutions for your actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `__generate__is_none(&self) -> bool` methods to the traits that return `true` only for `Option` containing `None`, then use that:

```rust
fn none_fields(&self) -> Vec<&'static str> {
    let mut result = Vec::new(); // Can use `with_capacity()` but this requires counting.
    $(
        if (&self.$field).__generate__is_none() {
            result.push(stringify!($field))
        }
    )*
    result
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c4f612ce095f237316de20ffa619d639).